# S3 + Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm currently fighting to get S3 uploads to work via Carrierwave, [Carrierwave-aws](https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws) & Figaro.

I've got it all set up but it keeps returning

'The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.'

**config/initializers/carrierwave.rb** (Set up according to carrierwave-aws)

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME')
  config.aws_acl    = 'public-read'

  # Optionally define an asset host for configurations that are fronted by a
  # content host, such as CloudFront.
  config.asset_host = 'http://example.com'

  # The maximum period for authenticated_urls is only 7 days.
  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

  # Set custom options such as cache control to leverage browser caching
  config.aws_attributes = {
    expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
    cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
  }

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    region:            ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION') # Required
  }

end
```

**Figaro application.yml**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "RANDOMNUMBERSKEY"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "RANDOMNUMBERSKEY"
S3_BUCKET_NAME: "random-bucket-123"
AWS_REGION: "us-west-2"
```

On AWS Console my Bucket is located in

**Region:   US Standard**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine, with the exception of the `asset_host`. You certainly don't have `example.com` as your asset host.